# put the 5 boxes with the same spacing and size

Tags: django, django-templates, frontend, bootstrap-5

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip1dU.png)

I would like to know how to display the date form in-line instead of stacked.
thank you in advance! :)

im using bootstrap and django so i tried solving the problem with bootstrap or even the django templating
but couldnt get nowhere.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 750px;"> 
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.name placeholder="Name" class+="form-control" %}</div>
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.phone placeholder="Phone" class+="form-control" %}</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row mb-4 ">
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.people placeholder="People" class+="form-control" %}</div>
            <div class="col " style="display: inline-flex;">{% render_field form.date class+="form-control " %}</div>
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.time placeholder="Time" class+="form-control" %}</div>            
        </div>
        
        <div class="row mx-auto">
        <button type="submit" value = "Refresh" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>




</div>
```

Comment: try adding code here itself it really reduces the time for who ever is solving! Thanks in advance.

Comment: just added the html in cause

Answer (score 0):

This may work please try and letme know

```
<div class="col-md-6">{% render_field form.date placeholder="Date" class="form-control" %}</div>
<div class="col-md-6">{% render_field form.time placeholder="Time" class="form-control" %}</div>
```

Comment: I think he means render the date input fields next to eachother.

Comment: hey! thx for your answer, i managed to get it in the same line, now i just wanted for all the 5 rectangles to take the same space, thanks! i already edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You tried bootstrap; some things are just as easy in regular CSS. It also gets the added benefit of modularity - working wherever you can use CSS.

Try the following css:

```css
.date-input-wrapper  {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.date-input-wrapper > .form-group {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Of course you'll have to properly wrap the parent element.
Let's hope your render_form method wraps the HTML like so:

```html
<div class="date-input-wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        label
        input
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        label
        input
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        label
        input
    </div>
</div>
```

If it gets rendered as:

```html
<div class="date-input-wrapper">
    <input class="form-group"/>
    <input class="form-group"/>
    <input class="form-group"/>
</div>
```

you can replace > .form-group with > input:

```
.date-input-wrapper > input {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

You could also do:

```
.date-input-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.date-input-wrapper input {
    flex: 1;
}
```

#### Edit

I think I know what you want now.
You need the following

```
div
   > div width:1/5 < People
   > div width:1/5 < Month
   > div width:1/5 < Day
   > div width:1/5 < Year
   > div width:1/5 < Time
```

I think you would be able to unpack the date field, this (I am not sure!) is probably done like this:

```
{% for field in form.date %}
    <div class="col>{% render_field field class+="form-control " %}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Can you try the following?

```
        <div class="row mb-4 ">
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.people placeholder="People" class+="form-control" %}</div>
            {% for field in form.date %}
                <div class="col>{% render_field field class+="form-control " %} </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="col">{% render_field form.time placeholder="Time" class+="form-control" %}</div>            
        </div>
```

Comment: hey! thx for your answer, i managed to get it in the same line, now i just wanted for all the 5 rectangles to take the same space, thanks! i already edited the post

Comment: Just saying, parent `display:flex` and `flex: 1` will probably work like magic in alignment! ;) Great for grid systems too!

Comment: on the div class? sorry my frontend knowledge is not very good

Comment: On the topmost elements you want next to eachother. `div > div.col*3`. Using emmet abbreviations, this basically means a parent div wrapping 3 child div elements. You would need to define `display: flex;flex-direction:row;` on that parent div; and `flex: 1;` on the `.col`

Comment: i think it didnt work, or maybe im doing something wrong. do you mind seeing the new image i put on the post?

Comment: didnt work either :/, says 'BoundWidget' object has no attribute 'as_widget'